# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error after execute query

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My `update` query sets the correct value but returns the following error in Yii2:

Error:
`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error`

Update query:

```
$query =Yii::$app->db
        ->createCommand('
    UPDATE fc_dore_reg 
    INNER JOIN fc_dore ON fc_dore.id = fc_dore_reg.dore_id SET fc_dore_reg.pay_all = 1 
    WHERE fc_dore_reg.user_id = "'.$user_id.'"
')->queryAll();
```

Why is this error occuring when `fc_dore_reg.pay_all = 1` is set correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use execute()

```
Yii::$app->db
        ->createCommand('
            UPDATE fc_dore_reg 
            INNER JOIN fc_dore ON fc_dore.id = fc_dore_reg.dore_id 
            SET fc_dore_reg.pay_all = 1 
            WHERE fc_dore_reg.user_id = "'.$user_id.'"')
        ->execute();
```

Remember that queryAll() Executes the SQL statement and returns ALL rows at once but there are no rows  to return in an update ..

Comment: yes. it works for this query. but my real query have multi `where` condition and does not work there.

Comment: I mean when value of `fc_dore_reg.pay_all` is `1` does not work

Comment: Seems like you have (or had) 2 separate issues - as @scaisEdge pointed out, you need to use `execute()` (and you should probably bind the $user_id value) -- and a MySql query problem: if the query works natively, there really shouldn't be any reason it won't work in this case (unless `user_id` is wrong), so not sure what you mean by it "does not work".